# How do I use generics with HashMap?

Tags: java, generics

I have two methods, one returns a HashMap of `<Integer,String>` and the other returns a HashMap of `<Integer, Spanned>`. Is there a way of using generics to make them into just one method?

```
public static Map<Integer, Spanned> queryGMGText() throws ParseException {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> positionQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("AndroidGMGContent");
    positionQuery.whereExists("position");
    List<ParseObject> ParsePositionResult = positionQuery.find();

    final Map<Integer,Spanned> appText = new HashMap<Integer,Spanned>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ParsePositionResult.size(); i++) {
        appText.put(ParsePositionResult.get(i).getInt("position"), Html.fromHtml(ParsePositionResult.get(i).getString("appText")));
    }

    return appText;
}

public static Map<Integer, String> queryGMG(String field) throws ParseException {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> positionQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("AndroidGMGContent");
    positionQuery.whereExists("position");
    List<ParseObject> ParsePositionResult = positionQuery.find();

    final Map<Integer,String> fieldMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ParsePositionResult.size(); i++) {
        fieldMap.put(ParsePositionResult.get(i).getInt("position"), ParsePositionResult.get(i).getString(field));
    }

    return fieldMap;
}
```

and if so, how would I instantiate and call them? Currently I'm doing it this way (from another class):

```
Map<Integer,Spanned> appTextMap = new HashMap<Integer,Spanned>();
    try {
        appTextMap = ParseContent.queryGMGText();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
// now I can use it, i.e.
Spanned s = appTextMap.get(1);
```

Comment: Huh? `Spanned` and `String` are different types, and `String` is final so you can't extend it using OOP inheritance. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: The two functions do different things. One takes an argument and passes that argument to `getString`; the other doesn't take an argument, passes "appText" instead, and then takes the result of `Html.fromHtml()`. Generics is only for things that work identically in every way for every type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a single map, requires no explicit casting, but does require knowing the type for each key. Maybe not a perfect fit, but maybe this gives you some ideas to build the right solution? Hope it helps,

```
public class CustomMap {

      private Map<String, Object> _map;

      public CustomMap(){
         _map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
      }  

      public <T> void setTypeValueByKey(Integer key, T value) {
         _map.put(key.toString(), value);
      }

      public <T> T getTypeValueByKey(Class<T> klass, Integer key) {
         return klass.cast(_map.get(key.toString()));
      }

      public static void main(String[] o){
         CustomMap map = new CustomMap();
         map.setTypeValueByKey(new Integer(1), new Spanned() );
         map.setTypeValueByKey(new Integer(2), new String("foo"));         

         Spanned spanned = 
           map.getTypeValueByKey(Spanned.class, new Integer(1));
         String foo = 
           map.getTypeValueByKey(String.class, new Integer(2));                  
      }

   static class Spanned{}
}
```

So you have three options:

- explicit casting using `Map<Integer,Object>`, jkschneider's solution
- aspects of my solution above
- or, `Map<Integer,<? extends MyBaseClass>>`, where `Spanned` and a `String`-like class extends `MyBaseClass`

Comment: You say this requires no casting, yet there's a call to `klass.cast()` right there.

Comment: Yes, but it's not explicit casting, it's more efficient, and works for all type values contained in `_map`, it's also hidden from users of `CustomMap`

Answer (score 1):

### Strictly answering the question:

Since there is no commonality in the inheritance tree of `Spanned` and `String`, you would have to alter the methods to return `Map<Integer, Object>` and then could:

```
try {
    Map<Integer, Object> appTextMap = ParseContent.queryGMGText();
    // now I can use it, i.e.
    Spanned s = (Spanned) appTextMap.get(1);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This kind of defeats the purpose of generics of course, but serves to shine a light on the true problem here.

### Reconsidering the original code:

Of course it seems far better to rewrite the whole thing to something like the following.  The only difference between the two functions is the `Html.forHtml(..)` call.  Let's assume for a moment (without loss of generality) that you really want the `String` and not `Spanned`:

```
public static Map<Integer, String> queryGMGAppText() throws ParseException {
    return queryGMG("appText");
}

public static Map<Integer, String> queryGMG(String field) throws ParseException {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> positionQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("AndroidGMGContent");
    positionQuery.whereExists("position");
    List<ParseObject> ParsePositionResult = positionQuery.find();

    final Map<Integer,String> fieldMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ParsePositionResult.size(); i++) {
        fieldMap.put(ParsePositionResult.get(i).getInt("position"), ParsePositionResult.get(i).getString(field));
    }

    return fieldMap;
}
```

Perhaps you don't really need `queryGMGAppText()` at all.  Are you calling it in so many places that it is important to have this convenience method?

Comment: This sort of defeats the purpose of generics; explicit casting, that is.

Comment: @raffian - Undoubtedly... of course the original question itself isn't a good use of generics.

Comment: You're right, I posted my solution, but no easy way around this :-)